# Combine list of ZIO ZStreams into one

Tags: scala, amazon-sqs, zio

My old code supported consuming one SQS queue with an SqsStream. I have to update it to support multiple queues given a list of queue URLs.

Method content:

```
for {
  sqs <- Sqs.>.async // async client
  urls <- Sqs.>.queueUrls // List[String] of multiple queues
  _ <- {
    urls
      .map(url => {
        SqsStream(sqs, url, SqsStreamSettings(autoDelete = false))
          .mapMParUnordered(10)(handleMessage) // run "handleMessage" up to 10 times concurrently, ZStream[Env, Throwable, Unit]
          .runDrain // ZIO[Env, Throwable, Unit]
          .forever // ZIO[Env, Throwable, Nothing]
      })
} yield ()
```

but the compiler complains because it expects a (ZIO, ZIO, ZIO) whereas I gave it a (ZIO, ZIO, List). I'm assuming I have to reduce all the effects in that list into a single effect that will execute `handleMessage` parallely across all queues, but I'm not sure about the syntax as I have no experience with ZIO.

Essentially by this point,

```
urls
      .map(url => {
        SqsStream(sqs, url, SqsStreamSettings(autoDelete = false))
```

my url became a ZStream. I think I need to call `ZStream.flatMapPar` using this element and the next, and so on so forth until all of them are flattened together. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`runDrain` will return a `ZIO` which you can fire and forget with `foreachPar_`.

```
for {
  sqs <- Sqs.>.async
  urls <- Sqs.>.queueUrls
  // Returns ZIO[R, E, Unit] and executes each effect in parallel while discarding the results
  _ <- ZIO.foreachPar_(urls) { url =>
        SqsStream(sqs, url, SqsStreamSettings(autoDelete = false))
          // Handles up to 10 messages at a time in parallel.
          .mapMParUnordered(10)(handleMessage)
          // The stream is already unbounded so no need to have `.forever`
          .runDrain
      }
} yield ()
```

I'd also clarify that the `SqsStream` should already be unbounded, so you shouldn't need to use `forever`, and the `mapMParUnordered` parameter refers to the max concurrency not the total number of events processed.